# Crystal Reports 8.5 SetDataSource generates empty error message

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a VB6 application that uses Crystal Reports 8.5 to view reports. I now have created a new report that uses an SQL Server stored procedure as a data source. When viewing this report in my application I use a `ADODB.Recordset` as a data source for the report. The problem is that Crystal Reports fails to show the report. It only shows an empty database error message, and an informational warning that the "Server has not yet been opened.".

I googled like my life depends on it but I only found examples of wokring situations that do exactly what I am doing. Sometimes with some minor differences but I tried them all. They keep ending with the same error messages.

This is my code to fill the recordset.

```
Dim Records As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
Cmd.ActiveConnection = clSQL.DBConnection   '< -- Existing connection that uses CursorLocation adUseClient
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Cmd.CommandText = "SPCrystalReports"

Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("ReportType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, Soort)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("ReportFile", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, RapportNaam)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("Template", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, Template)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("WhereClause", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8000, CentralSQL)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("WhereClause2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8000, ExtraSQL)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("Date", adDate, adParamInput, , Datum)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("DateFrom", adDate, adParamInput, , DatumVan)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("DateTo", adDate, adParamInput, , DatumTot)

Set Records = Cmd.Execute

Set Cmd = Nothing
```

This is how I load my report:

```
Dim crApp As CRAXDRT.Application
Dim crRep As CRAXDRT.Report

Set crApp = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set crRep = crApp.OpenReport(ReportFile, 1)
```

And then I tried the folowing code samples to get the report working.

Sample 1:

```
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.SetDataSource Records
```

Sample 2:

```
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.SetDataSource Records, 3, 1
```

Sample 3:

```
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetLogOnInfo DBServer, DBDatabase, DBUser, DBPass
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.SetDataSource Records, 3, 1
```

Sample 4:

```
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetDataSource Records, 3
```

Sample 5:

```
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetLogOnInfo DBServer, DBDatabase, DBUser, DBPass
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetDataSource Records, 3
```

Sample 6:

```
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetPrivateData 3, Records
```

Sample 7:

```
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetLogOnInfo DBServer, DBDatabase, DBUser, DBPass
crRep.DiscardSavedData
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetPrivateData 3, Records
```

They all end up with this error popup followed by the information popup.

[image: Empty error message]
[image: Information popup]

How to get this working?

Comment: Tag your question with `sql-server` for it to receive more eye-balls from the much bigger DB sub-community.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no execution error and Records variable contains data, try with (Object Browser invisible) method SetPrivateData:

```
crRep.Database.Tables(1).SetPrivateData 3, Records
```

Pdsoledb.dll (p2soledb.dll) as crRep.Database.Tables(1).DllName indicates that your report should retrieve data from a database by itself, so try something like this:

```
With crRep.Database.Tables(1).ConnectionProperties
    .DeleteAll
    .Add "Connection String", " insert a connection string here "
End With
```

or use LogOnServer method like here [VB and Crystal Reports problem](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=465819)

or change report's connection type to Field Definitions Only.

Comment: Tried it but it gave the same error. Also tried combinations with `SetLogOnInfo`. I will add them to the list in my question.

Comment: What's crRep.Database.Tables(1).DllName and how many tables there are in crRep.Database.Tables collection?

Comment: DllName: pdsoledb.dll, and there is only 1 table.

Comment: I've edited my answer regarding crRep.Database.Tables(1).DllName

Comment: That the DllName indicates a database connection is correct. The report is build with an active database connection that needs to be "replaced" by a recordset at runtime. Als, there is no method `ConnectionProperties`. You probably have a different version of CR.

Comment: @Martin could you post a link to your rpt file?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible because of privacy concerns. The report would contain information that could identify my client. What would you like to do with the report?

Comment: I understand. My company switched from CR8 to CR11.5 and we developed some VB6 tools I thought might be helpful detecting the cause of your reporting problem.